# BuscarV que cambia de rango con referencias absolutas

Tags: excel

Tengo una tabla en una pestaña X, desde otra pestaña estoy haciendo un buscarv a la pestaña X

```
=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV($B8;'X'!$B:$V;4;0);0)
```

Si inserto una columna en la tabla que hay en la pestaña X, me mueve el rango `B:V` y me lo pasa al `C:V`

¿Cómo puedo mantenerlo?

Comment: Al insertar una columna, se actualizan las referencias siempre. Pero no puede ser que te lo cambie a `C:V` si tu rango original era `B:V`. Dependiendo de dónde insertes la nueva columna, te lo cambiará a `C:W` o `B:W`. Además, es que es lo correcto. Si tienes una tabla, y la cambias de posición, la formula se tiene que actualizar, y eso es lo que hace Excel.

Comment: A mi me desplaza en rango en lugar de ampliarlo.La columna la inserto a la izquierda de la B y cojo todo el rango de la hoja, si solo cojo e inserto una columna desde la B2 hasta el final, entonces no me desplaza el rango.

Answer (score 0):

Para tomar un rango fijo que se mantenga luego de insertar o eliminar celdas:

```
=BUSCARV($B8;INDIRECTO("'X'!$B:$V");4;FALSO)
```

Con [INDIRECTO()](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/indirecto-funci%C3%B3n-indirecto-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=es-es&rs=es-es&ad=es), el rango se pasa como texto (entre comillas) y nunca se va a correr.